# Transfer Struct to two different impl functions

Tags: struct, rust

The variable `screen` is an instance of the `Display` struct which contains the size of a screen. And `point` is an instance of another struct which contains a point in XY field. I have implemented two functions.

1. `is_point_inside_display` will return `true` if the point is inside of the screen, `false` otherwise.
2. `make_valid_point` will modify the "point" if the first function returns `false`.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Display {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Display {
    fn is_point_inside_display(&self, point: &Display) -> bool {
        self.x > point.x && self.y > point.y
    }

    fn make_valid_point(&self, point: &Display) {
        if !self.is_point_inside_display(point) {
            let x = point.x % self.x as i32;
            let y = point.y % self.y as i32;
            point.x = x;
            point.y = y;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let screen = Display {
        //the size of the display
        x: 1960,
        y: 1080,
    };
    let point = Display {
        //point in xy
        x: 450,
        y: 1230,
    };

    screen.make_valid_point(&point);
    println!("point in {:?}", point);
}
```

The problem is that I cannot modify `point` because it is not mutable, but if I make it mutable the compiler shows lots of error, which I do not understand.

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to `point.x` which is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/main.rs:16:13
   |
12 |     fn make_valid_point(&self, point: &Display) {
   |                                       -------- help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut Display`
...
16 |             point.x = x;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^ `point` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be written

error[E0594]: cannot assign to `point.y` which is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/main.rs:17:13
   |
12 |     fn make_valid_point(&self, point: &Display) {
   |                                       -------- help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut Display`
...
17 |             point.y = y;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^ `point` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be written
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please always include the error you get when compiling your program and/or the expected result (e.g. in this case it should compile :) ). Take yourself some time to view the edit I made to your post and try to understand why and what I did. Also note that variables in rust are immutable by default, so you need to pass a mutable reference (or by value) to the function. Please edit your code, update your question by [edit]ing it and don't forget to update the error message as well. Also the compiler will almost always tell you what to do. Just listen to it :)

Comment: Just like the compiler suggests, add a few `mut`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2db538b587840c3c7f1c6102e16e7b32 . Looking at the compiler suggestion is usually a good idea.

Comment: Thank you, hellow for your editing and kind suggestions. Now the question's body looks great and organized. Denys seguret thanks a lot, now it is working. That was a silly mistake. I got the answer. do i need to close/delete the question.